# Eclipse Luna craches with JVM terminated.exit code=1

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using eclipse Luna on Xubuntu 14.10, it worked well.
when i launch eclipse sometimes it crached, sometimes it worked well at the first time then it crached suddenly with this error.

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /usr/local/eclipse-luna/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /usr/local/eclipse-luna/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400/splash.bmp
-launcher /usr/local/eclipse-luna/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/local/eclipse-luna/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so
-startup /usr/local/eclipse-luna/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 20e801f
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /usr/local/eclipse-luna/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

there is my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

i used openjdk7, when i typed `java -version`,

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

My Eclipse's version is the the good one, the 64 bits
I looked at the others posts which treat the same probleme but the solutions which proposed didn't helpe me.

what can I do please. Any thoughts?

Thank you for advance.

Comment: Do you see any logs that you can paste ? (if it crashes at launch, it's probably under `configuration` folder)

Comment: Did you tried to uninstall then install again java ?

Comment: Also see <workspace>/.metadata/.log file for possible error messages.

Comment: I uninstalled and installed both eclipse and java version. There is no error in my log file. I only saw this message on the terminal, The program 'Eclipse' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 66315 error_code 3 request_code 3 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a Xubuntu Bug, i found a solution from this link, 
[Bug 11893 - Eclipse crashes frequently with Xfce 4.12](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11893)

There were two choices :

1. use another windows manager like openbox for exemple.
2. try to downgrade the xfwm4 (Xubuntu 15.04), but i coudn't then i used openbox, and eclipse work well.

i hope that can help someone.